# jQuery using form generated by $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

jQuery newbie here with a problem ...

I am doing some server-side validation and generating a new form with 'confirm' & 'cancel' buttons using an $.ajax call. This works OK, but I would then like to do the same to process the confirm/cancel buttons on the form that is created, but this not working.

The 'confirm' button is not invoking the new $.ajax call and I suspect because it has been dynamically generated by a previous $.ajax call, it is not 'live' as far as jQuery is concerned.

My jQuery javascript code is:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //if submit button is clicked on order form
    $('#submit').click(function () {

        //show the loading sign
        $('.loading').show();


        $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/ajax_checkorder.asp',
            type: "GET",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                var message = (typeof response.jsonresp) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.jsonresp + ')') : response.jsonresp;
                $('#message').empty();
                if (message[0].ok == '1') {
                    $('#intromsg').hide('slow');
                }
                $('#message').append(message[0].msg);
            },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

        //cancel the submit button default behaviours
        return false;
    });

    //if submit button is clicked on confirmation form
$('#confirm').live('confirm', function () {

    $(this).click(function () {

        //show the loading sign
        $('.loading').show();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/ajax_sendorder.asp',
            type: "GET",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                var message = (typeof response.jsonresp) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.jsonresp + ')') : response.jsonresp;
                $('#message').empty();
                if (message[0].ok == '1') {
                    $('#ordermsg').hide('slow');
                }
                $('#message').append(message[0].msg);
            },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks for any help!

epx

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicions are correct.  You'll need to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) then [rebind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) the click event for the 'confirm' button since the first event is bound to something that is no longer on the dom (even though it has the same ID).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the .click() only applies to what currently exists. Best thing to do would be to put the stuff in your .click() into a wrapper function and call it in your document.ready but then call it again in your .ajax callback to reapply it to the returned content.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked the code during an execution, but it may work if you encapsulate the #confirm binding into another function and call it when the first call is successful.

```
function bindConfirm() {
    $('#confirm').live('confirm', function () {

        $(this).click(function () {

            //show the loading sign
            $('.loading').show();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'inc/ajax_sendorder.asp',
                type: "GET",
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    var message = (typeof response.jsonresp) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.jsonresp + ')') : response.jsonresp;
                    $('#message').empty();
                    if (message[0].ok == '1') {
                        $('#ordermsg').hide('slow');
                    }
                    $('#message').append(message[0].msg);
                },
                error: function (xhr, err) {
                    alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                    alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
      });
    });
}
```

After that, just call bindConfirm() when the ajax call succeeds. Greetings.

Comment: OK, I'm half way there. I have added the wrapper function and am calling it after the first $.ajax call is successful, so now the second ajax call is invoked ...

Comment: OK, I'm half way there. I have added the wrapper function and am calling it after the first $.ajax call is successful, so now the second ajax call is invoked from the 'confirm' button ... but ... the confirm button has to be clicked twice because the first time round the ajax call is not made. What do I need to do to call the ajax routine on the first click? (The code is as in Kor's response above)

Comment: I noticed that I didn't pay full attention to each line of your code and I didn't see that `.live()` call (I actually supposed you were directly binding a `click` event). Have you tried it without the `.live()` nesting level (so you directly register the `click` event)? Anyway, wrapping your code can also be helpful for calling it back elsewhere. Have you tried to  call `bindConfirm()` right after the document is ready? That would only make sense if you call it once or `live` isn't there. Also, it may be better to JSON.parse(response.jsonresp)` instead of `eval('(' + response.jsonresp + ')')`

Answer (score 0):

use livequery jquery plugin it will make your life easier..
[livequery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery)

attach to the request which is creating data on the fly.